# OpenLayers 3+: Start/end icons

Tags: openlayers, gpx, title, segment

How to create markers/icons at the startpoint and endpoint automatically in OL/JS? I'm doing this right now - I know startpoint and endpoint from PHP analysis:

```
var startpoint = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.fromLonLat([xx.xxx,xx.xxx])
  )
});
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [startpoint]
});
var start = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  renderBuffer: 0
});
start.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
            color: 'green',
            src: '/gpx/start.png',
            anchor: [0.6, 1]        })
        }));
map.addLayer(start);
```

So I'm trying something like this:

```
source.on("drawstart", function(e1) {    
var startpoint=map.getEventCoordinate(e1);`

...

start.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
            color: 'green',
            src: '/gpx/start.png',
            anchor: [0.6, 1]        })
        }));
map.addLayer(start);
});
```

but without success.

Comment: You can use a style function which adds point geometry styles at points on a linestring as in this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/line-arrows.html

Comment: You're right but:
`ReferenceError: VectorLayer is not defined`
or
`TypeError: ol.VectorLayer is not a constructor`
:(

Comment: It would be easier to use the version 4 example if you need the full build syntax https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/line-arrows.html

Comment: Do you know which part of code does round point of the end of route?

Comment: Here is another example https://jsfiddle.net/uwjzyeqx/1/ based on https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop.html which adds start, end and km markers from MapQuest's Icons API to a gpx linestring.

Comment: I've got it! It's amazing! And one detail: Can I show the details of the kilometer (average speed, time, elevation +/-) after click on KM image?

Comment: Sooo: I show kilometer in HTML div right now. I can show only kilometer's number - can I show the time of the kilometer and +- elevation?

`var kms = ol.sphere.getLength(lineString) / 1000;`

`for (var i = 1; i < kms; i++) {` - can I get the time and the elevation too?

Comment: Strangely getCoordinateAt does not return elevation and time from the linestring, but getClosestPoint does https://jsfiddle.net/djzoypt3/

Comment: Your code is amazing. Thanks, thanks, thanks!